# How to display datetime-local from database using jquery

Tags: html, jquery, mysql, date, datetime

I have an event calendar where it includes CRUD. Everything works fine but I couldn't display the start and end date on the edit modal. Previously I used moment.js so I used

```
 $('#ModalEdit #start').val(moment(event.start).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss'));
```

But due to certain reasons, now I'm using datetime-local function and I'm not sure how to display the date from the database. Or is there any other plugin that I can use to do them? Below is the code:

```
 <script>
 $(document).ready(function() {

  eventRender: function(event, element) {
                element.bind('dblclick', function() { 
                    $('#ModalEdit #id').val(event.id);
                    $('#ModalEdit #title').val(event.title);
                    $('#ModalEdit #color').val(event.color);
                    $('#ModalEdit #start').val(event.start);
                    $('#ModalEdit #end').val(event.end);
                    $('#ModalEdit').modal('show');
        });
      }
    });
    </script>

 <div class="modal fade" id="ModalEdit" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
 
 <form method="POST" action="editEventTitle.php">
               
  <div>
     <label for="title">Activity</label>
     <textarea id="title" name="title></textarea>
  </div>
                   
  <div>
      <label for="start">Date and Time</label>
      <input type="datetime-local" name="start" id="start">
    </div>
                    
    <div>
      <label for="end">End date</label>
      <input type="datetime-local" name="end" id="end">
    </div>

    <div class="checkbox">
       <label class="text-danger"><input type="checkbox"  name="delete"> Delete event</label>
     </div>
    <input type="hidden" name="id" class="form-control" id="id">

     <div class="modal-footer">
       <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success    ">Save changes</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
```

Comment: You need a server-side code (node.js, php, C#, etc) that connects to the database and queries the data and sends it to the webbrowser where your jquery code can pick it up.

Comment: look for REST API and jquery